# What is the topology of the Hitchin component?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, gt.geometric-topology, teichmuller-theory

Let $S$ be a closed orientable connected surface of genus $g\geq2$.

In *[Lie groups and Teichmüller space](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/004093839290044I)* Hitchin shows that one of the component of $\chi(S)=\operatorname{Hom}^{+}(\pi_1(S),\operatorname{SL}_3(\mathbb{R}))/\operatorname{SL}_3(\mathbb{R})$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{16g-16}$ (where ${}^{+}$ is here to denote the subset of representations that acts completely reducibly on $\mathfrak{sl}_3(\mathbb{R})$). We call it the Hitchin component.

There is a bijection between connected components of $\chi(S)$ and $\operatorname{Hom}(\pi_1(S),\operatorname{SL}_3(\mathbb{R}))$. So my question is:
what is the topology of the connected component of $\operatorname{Hom}(\pi_1(S),\operatorname{SL}_3(\mathbb{R}))$ corresponding to the Hitchin component?

Comment: Hint: It is a principal $G$-bundle over a contractible base.